# Regression analysis if one of dependent variable is almost constant

Tags: regression

While doing multi-variate regression, i am encountering cases like below image, where for one of dimension, apart from couple of data points all values are same. Cause of this, model is going haywire.

[image]

What's right way to handle these cases ?

Also these outlier points are not explained by other dimensions also.

```
 1. remove these points as outlier ?
 2. ?
```

Comment: Offhand, I'd call them outliers. But, are those observations outliers only wrt this variable, or others as well?

Comment: That is a beautiful plot.  Can you provide source code?

Answer (score 2):

Is this of those cases of trying to use statistics to replace logic? :)
At any rate, one way to handle this is to run [ANOVA](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/anovareg.htm) on two different models, one using the doubtful variable, the other without. Or just look at the two models adjusted $R^2$ and discard the variable if there isn't a significant improvement.

Another way to study the variable is to see whether it could be discretized and treated as a [categorical variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable). For example, when the value is different than its mean (or the large number of same-value observations), does it indicate something substantially different? Could you logically reduce the continuous values to two or three different outcomes?

Comment: Even if he reduces it to a categorical variable, he will have 5 points in one category, not sure it will yield interesting results.

Comment: It will have 5 points where the dummy is set to 1, all others 0 (or maybe one level for negatives away from mean, one for positives and one for the cluster of values). How do you know it won't yield interesting results?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of variable is it ? Are you sure you want to include it ?

It is indeed rather bad for the estimation, but even if the estimation worked well you probably would not be able to say really interesting things about it, given you lack individuals to make sense of it.

Comment: I actually want to remove it only as model will be bad. Question is: how to identify such cases ?